# Getting Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am getting a Javascript error from the code below, however, I am only getting it for some records while others process as expected.  There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason why.  Does anyone have any ideas?  This is a custom button that sits on a custom object and is mean to submit the record to a standard SFDC approval process.

*A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
Invalid or unexpected token*

***Javascript:***

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")} 
if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Offer_Scope__c }' == '' || '{! SBQQ__Quote__c.Justification_for_Discounting__c}' == '' || 
'{! SBQQ__Quote__c.Client_Background__c }' == '' || 
'{! SBQQ__Quote__c.Additional_Fee_Requests__c }' == '' || 
'{! SBQQ__Quote__c.Non_Standard_Terms__c }' == '' ) 
{ 
var message = 'Please complete the Approval Request Information section before submitting this Quote for approval. The following fields are missing: '; 

message += '\n'; 

if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Offer_Scope__c }' == ''){ 
message += '\nMissing Offer Scope'; 
} 
if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Additional_Fee_Requests__c }' == ''){ 
message += '\nAdditional Fee Requests'; 
} 
if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Justification_for_Discounting__c }' == ''){ 
message += '\nMissing Justification for Discounting'; 
} 
if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Client_Background__c }' == ''){ 
message += '\nMissing Client Background'; 
} 
if('{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Non_Standard_Terms__c }' == ''){ 
message += '\nMissing Non-Standard Terms Indicator'; 
} 
alert(message); 
} 
else { 
window.top.location.href = "{!URLFOR($Action.SBQQ__Quote__c.Submit, SBQQ__Quote__c.Id )}"; 
}
```

Comment: The reason is you have a field with a `'` in it somewhere (for some records, obviously). Solution is on the linked question.

Comment: This was not a duplicate requiring JSENCODE.  It was due to the fields above being Rich Text fields and containing bullets.  I fixed it by looking for Null values in the fields instead of "".